# How to map JAVA enum to Postgresql Enum using Hibernate/JPA?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, enums

In my Hibernate application, I want to map Java enum to Postgresql enum and vice-versa.

My application is using apache-thrift,hibernate/JPA(for ORM model),postgresql DB.

Postgresql DB have defined enum using command

```
CREATE TYPE status_enum AS ENUM ('UNDER-CONSTRUCTION', 'CLOSED', 'OPEN')
```

DB has some data initially few tuples have 'UNDER-CONSTRUCTION' status.

Here is my solution:

Custom Type for enum mapping:

```
public class PsqlEnum extends EnumType {

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(final PreparedStatement st, final Object value, final int index,
            final SharedSessionContractImplementor session) throws SQLException {
        if(value == null) {
            st.setNull( index, Types.OTHER );
        }
        else {
            st.setObject(
                    index,
                    value.toString(),
                    Types.OTHER
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Entity for ORM(hibernate) model :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "place")
@TypeDef(
        name = "pgsql_enum",
        typeClass = PsqlEnum.class
)
public class Place implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id",nullable = false)
    @Getter @Setter private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    @Getter @Setter private String name;


    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Type(type = "pgsql_enum")
    @Column(name = "status_level",columnDefinition = "status_enum")
    private STATUS status;
}
```

Enum Class :

```
public enum STATUS{
    CLOSED("CLOSED"),
    UNDERCONSTRUCTION("UNDER-CONSTRUCTION"),
    OPEN("OPEN");
    private final String label;
    Exposure(String label){
        this.label = label;
    }
    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public static STATUS fromLabel(String label){
        for(STATUS currentEnum:STATUS.values()){
            if(currentEnum.getLabel().equals(label)){
                return currentEnum;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.label;
    }
}
```

It works fine on insertion operation while on retrieving data it throws an error : `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown name value [UNDER-CONSTRUCTION] for enum class`

I tried every given reference solution in StackOverflow no one is working fine for my problem.

Comment: if possible rename psql enum `UNDER-CONSTRUCTION` to `UNDERCONSTRUCTION`. So it matches the enum you defined in java

Comment: @Lino This is live DB used by other person also.So I can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate uses function `name()` of `Enum` when it serialize value of enumerated field and `Enum.valueOf(...)` when it is deserialize entity.

Thats why you cant use `"UNDER-CONSTRUCTION"` in values

Answer (score 0):

So I am able to figure out what I was missing. Basically I have to override both nullSafeGet and nullSafeSet in PsqlEnum.java file.
I reached to solution by following this [java file](https://gist.github.com/jedvardsson/96af1b86f78762ac12ef#file-labeledenumtype-java).
So Either define custom UserType like defined in link or custom EnumType both worked for me.
In above code PsqlEnum.java in custom EnumType I was missing overriding  nullSafeGet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the possible solution you also need to override the `nullSafeGet` in the `PsqlEnum` class.

```
@Override
public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names,  SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
    String name = rs.getString(names[0]);
    if(rs.wasNull()) return  null;

    try {
        Field field = getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("enumClass");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Class value = (Class) field.get(this);
        Optional<Object> object =  Arrays.stream(value.getEnumConstants()).filter(o -> o.toString().equals(name)).findFirst();
        return object.orElseThrow(() ->   new IllegalArgumentException(
            "No enum constant " + value + "." + name));
    } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
        return super.nullSafeGet(rs, names, session, owner);
    }
}
```